# javascript - In an array of objects, returns objects where ANY value matches a specific string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, filtering

I'm implementing search functionality into my application. The search results in the UI are returned based on an array of objects. Essentially what I'm trying to do is iterate over the name, custNumber, and sneak values in each object, and only return the objects that contain a value that includes a string (generated from the users search bar). The idea is that users can search for anything in the object and yield the correct results

here is my array

```
var result = [{
  name: 'Donna Shomaker',
  custNumber: '6658924351',
  sneak: 'string1 string1 string1',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Ron Duluth',
  custNumber: '8812654434',
  sneak: 'string2 string2 string2',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Jimmy Dawson',
  custNumber: '8908198230',
  sneak: 'string3 string3 string3',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
}
]
```

This is how far I've gotten

```
return result.filter(convo => {
  return convo.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchbarVal.toLowerCase())
})
```

The obvious problem here is that this only is only returning objects based on the name value. However, I need it to compare the name, custNumber, and sneak values in each object to the users search. I've tried forEach, object.values, and object.entries methods and haven't been able to get them to work. Any help here is much appreciated!!

Comment: Check this question and answer. It may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

**recursive search**

This is a topic I've written about [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50456572/633183). Here is a generic `deepFind`. It works recursively and can "search" any input value.

Below we construct a simple set of `data` and then show how `deepFind` can search the data and return matches

```js
const data =
  [ { a: 1, b: 1 }
  , { a: 2, b: 2, c: { d: [ { e: 2 } ] } }
  , { a: 3, b: { c: { d: { e: { f: 3 } } } } }
  ]

const deepFind = (f, obj = {}) =>
{ if (Object (obj) === obj)
  { if (f (obj) === true)
      return obj

    for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries (obj))
    { const res =
        deepFind (f, v)

      if (res !== undefined)
        return res
    }
  }

  return undefined
}

console.log
  ( deepFind (x => x.a === 1, data)             // { a: 1, b: 1 }
  , deepFind (x => x.e === 2, data)             // { e: 2 }
  , deepFind (x => Array.isArray(x.d), data)    // { d: [ { e: 2 } ] }
  , deepFind (x => x.f === 3, data)             // { f: 3 }
  , deepFind (x => x.e && x.e.f === 3, data)    // { e: { f: 3 } }
  , deepFind (x => x.z === 9, data)             // undefined
  )
```

Above `deepFind` only works by matching values directly using `===`. Because it accepts a higher-order function `f` however, we can specialize its behavior in meaningful ways.

**string match using `deepFind`**

Below we encode our generic string-matching `search` function using `deepFind`

```
const search = (query = "", data) =>
  deepFind
    ( o =>
        Object.values (o) .some (v =>
          String (v) === v && v .includes (query))
    , data
    )

search ("D", result)
// { name: "Donna Shomaker", ... }

search ("Du", result)
// { name: "Ron Duluth", ... }

search ("ng3", result)
// { name: "Jimmy Dawson", sneak: "string3 string3 string3", ... }

search ("zzz", result)
// undefined
```

Verify the results in your own browser

```js
const deepFind = (f, obj = {}) =>
{ if (Object (obj) === obj)
  { if (f (obj) === true)
      return obj

    for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries (obj))
    { const res =
        deepFind (f, v)
      
      if (res !== undefined)
        return res
    }
  }

  return undefined
}

const search = (query = "", data) =>
  deepFind
    ( o =>
        Object.values (o) .some (v =>
          String (v) === v && v .includes (query))
    , data
    )

const result =
  [ { name: 'Donna Shomaker'
    , custNumber: '6658924351'
    , sneak: 'string1 string1 string1'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  , { name: 'Ron Duluth'
    , custNumber: '8812654434'
    , sneak: 'string2 string2 string2'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  , { name: 'Jimmy Dawson'
    , custNumber: '8908198230'
    , sneak: 'string3 string3 string3'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  ]

console.log (search ("D", result))
// { name: "Donna Shomaker", ... }

console.log (search ("Du", result))
// { name: "Ron Duluth", ... }

console.log (search ("ng3", result))
// { name: "Jimmy Dawson", sneak: "string3 string3 string3", ... }

console.log (search ("zzz", result))
// undefined
```

**returning multiple search results**

The program above only returns the *first* match. If you wanted to return all of the results, we can do so using generators, which are perfectly suited for this task

```
const deepFindAll = function* (f, o = {})
{ if (Object (o) === o)
  { if (f (o) === true)
      yield o
    for (const [ _, v ] of Object.entries (o))
      yield* deepFindAll (f, v)
  }
}
```

Now we implement `searchAll` using our new generator

```
const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( o =>
            Object.values (o) .some (v =>
              String (v) === v && v .includes (query))
        , data
        )
    )

searchAll ("81", result)
// [ { custNumber: '8812654434', ... }
// , { custNumber: '8908198230', ... }
// ]

searchAll ("Du", result)
// [ { name: "Ron Duluth", ... } ]

searchAll ("zzz", result)
// []
```

Run `searchAll` in your browser below

```js
const deepFindAll = function* (f, o = {})
{ if (Object (o) === o)
  { if (f (o) === true)
      yield o
    for (const [ _, v ] of Object.entries (o))
      yield* deepFindAll (f, v)
  }
}

const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( o =>
            Object.values (o) .some (v =>
              String (v) === v && v .includes (query))
        , data
        )
    )

const result =
  [ { name: 'Donna Shomaker'
    , custNumber: '6658924351'
    , sneak: 'string1 string1 string1'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  , { name: 'Ron Duluth'
    , custNumber: '8812654434'
    , sneak: 'string2 string2 string2'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  , { name: 'Jimmy Dawson'
    , custNumber: '8908198230'
    , sneak: 'string3 string3 string3'
    , foo: false
    , bar: false
    }
  ]

console.log (searchAll ("81", result))
// [ { custNumber: '8812654434', ... }
// , { custNumber: '8908198230', ... }
// ]

console.log (searchAll ("Du", result))
// [ { name: "Ron Duluth", ... } ]

console.log (searchAll ("zzz", result))
// []
```

**case insensitive search**

Above, our `search` function uses `v .includes (query)` but because we're working with a higher-order function, we can make the behaviour as specific as we want.

Using `searchAll` as an example, we *could* change it like below

```
const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( o =>
            Object.values (o) .some (v =>
              String (v) === v && v .includes (query))
              String (v) === v
                && v .toLowerCase () .includes (query .toLowerCase ()))
        , data
        )
    )
```

But that's making a complete mess of our function. It's time to abstract a little more and explain what we're doing by giving our intentions names

```
const anyString = f => o =>
  Object.values (o) .some (v =>
    String (v) === v && f (v))

const caseInsenstiveMatch = (x, y) =>
  x.toLowerCase () .includes (y.toLowerCase ())

const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( anyString (v =>
            caseInsenstiveMatch (v, query))
        , data
        )
    )
```

Isolating behaviors and defining separate functions is an important part of writing good programs. Showing `search` and `searchAll` side-by-side highlights this importance. The new helpers `anyString` and `caseInsensitiveSearch` keep the code clear, but also make it easier to reuse behaviours where needed.

```
const search = (query = "", data) =>
  deepFind
    ( anyString (v =>
        caseInsenstiveMatch (v, query))
    , data
    )

const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( anyString (v =>
            caseInsenstiveMatch (v, query))
        , data
        )
    )
```

**contramap**

Higher-order functions have all sorts of uses for keeping our code clean and descriptive. Below, we define dead-simple versions of `match` and `lower`. Then using `contramap`, we bring our program together.

The emphasis here is on the simplicity of each function. A simple function is easier to test, easier to debug, and easier to combine with other simple functions. The Unix philosophy, [*"Do one thing and do it well"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well) should be ringing in your ears right now

```
const contramap = (f, g) =>
  (x, y) => f (g (x), g (y))

const match = (x = "", y = "") =>
  x .includes (y)

const lower = (x = "") =>
  x .toLowerCase ()

const caseInsenstiveMatch =
  contramap (match, lower)

const anyString = (f) => (o = {}) =>
  Object.values (o) .some (v =>
    String (v) === v && f (v))

const searchAll = (query = "", data = {}) =>
  Array.from
    ( deepFindAll
        ( anyString (v =>
            caseInsenstiveMatch (v, query))
        , data
        )
    )
```

Contramap unlocks other powers that may not be immediately obvious. If it interests you, I recommend [*Monoidal Contravariant Functors are actually useful!*](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4) by Brian Lonsdorf. Don't let the title scare you; the author has a knack for making this stuff easy.

Comment: This works great - the only problem here is that I was trying to avoid case-sensitive search queries. You'll notice in my original post I have two toLowercase methods (one for the search val, one for the values in the objects). So if a user inputs 'ron', it would still need to return the 'Ron" object

Comment: The idea behind using the higher-order function here is that you can specify that behavior where it's needed while keeping the base function generic. For case-insensitive matching, you can modify `search` or `searchAll` to `String (v) === v.toLowerCase () && v .includes (query.toLowerCase ())`. I'm going to make another edit to show you another way, too.

Answer (score 0):

A 'some' in your filter might do the trick, checking all the keys.

```
return result.filter(convo => {
  return Object.keys(convo).some(key => {
     return convo[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchbarVal.toLowerCase())
  })
})
```

Comment: OP sample data contains boolean values, which will throw an error if you call toLowerCase on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchObj(search){
  let answer = [];
  result.forEach(re => {
    if(JSON.stringify(re).indexOf(search) > 0){
      answer.push(re)
    }
  });
  return answer;
}
```

Loop through every element of the array, convert them into a string and use `indexOf` to find the matching criteria. That way you can save a few loops without looping each and every key of every element.

Comment: If search is "}" your function will match all objects, whereas this char is not part of OP's sample values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let search= result.filter(x=> ['name','custNumber','sneak']
     .reduce((o,a)=> x[a].toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())||o, false) );
```

Where `query` is your `searchbarVal.toLowerCase()`

```js
var result = [{
  name: 'Donna Shomaker',
  custNumber: '6658924351',
  sneak: 'string1 string1 string1',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Ron Duluth',
  custNumber: '8812654434',
  sneak: 'string2 string2 string2',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Jimmy Dawson',
  custNumber: '8908198230',
  sneak: 'string3 string3 string3',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
}
]

let query="89"; // searchbarVal.toLowerCase()

let search= result.filter(x=> ['name','custNumber','sneak'].reduce((o,a)=> x[a].toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())||o, false) );

console.log(search);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the object and try and do something like the following:

```js
var result = [{
  name: 'Donna Shomaker',
  custNumber: '6658924351',
  sneak: 'string1 string1 string1',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Ron Duluth',
  custNumber: '8812654434',
  sneak: 'string2 string2 string2',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
},
{
  name: 'Jimmy Dawson',
  custNumber: '8908198230',
  sneak: 'string3 string3 string3',
  foo: false,
  bar: false,
}
];

var searchStr = "Donna";

console.log(searchObj(searchStr));

function searchObj(search){
  var searchResult = [];
  for(var obj in result){
      var str = JSON.stringify(result[obj]);
      if(str.indexOf(search) > 0){
        searchResult.push(result[obj]);
      }
  }
  return searchResult;
}
```