# Recursive tree search in a nested object structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree

I'm trying to figure out how to search for a node in this JSON object recursively. I have tried something but cannot get it:

```
var tree = {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "A",
    "child": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "B",
            "child": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "label": "E",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "label": "F",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "label": "G",
                    "child": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "C",
            "child": []
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "label": "D",
            "child": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "label": "H",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "label": "I",
                    "child": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Here is my non-working solution, which is probably because the first node is just a value while children are in arrays:

```
function scan(id, tree) {
    if(tree.id == id) {
        return tree.label;
    }

    if(tree.child == 0) {
        return
    }

    return scan(tree.child);
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is just missing a loop to inspect each child of a node in the `child` array. This recursive function will return the `label` property of a node or `undefined` if label not present in tree:

```js
const search = (tree, target) => {
  if (tree.id === target) {
    return tree.label;
  }
  
  for (const child of tree.child) {
    const found = search(child, target);
    
    if (found) {
      return found;
    }
  }
};

const tree = {"id":1,"label":"A","child":[{"id":2,"label":"B","child":[{"id":5,"label":"E","child":[]},{"id":6,"label":"F","child":[]},{"id":7,"label":"G","child":[]}]},{"id":3,"label":"C","child":[]},{"id":4,"label":"D","child":[{"id":8,"label":"H","child":[]},{"id":9,"label":"I","child":[]}]}]};

console.log(search(tree, 1));
console.log(search(tree, 6));
console.log(search(tree, 99));
```

You can also do it iteratively with an explicit stack which won't cause a stack overflow (but note that the shorthand `stack.push(...curr.child);` can overflow the argument size for some JS engines due to the spread syntax, so use an explicit loop for massive child arrays):

```js
const search = (tree, target) => {
  for (const stack = [tree]; stack.length;) {
    const curr = stack.pop();
    
    if (curr.id === target) {
      return curr.label;
    }

    stack.push(...curr.child);
  }
};

const tree = {"id":1,"label":"A","child":[{"id":2,"label":"B","child":[{"id":5,"label":"E","child":[]},{"id":6,"label":"F","child":[]},{"id":7,"label":"G","child":[]}]},{"id":3,"label":"C","child":[]},{"id":4,"label":"D","child":[{"id":8,"label":"H","child":[]},{"id":9,"label":"I","child":[]}]}]};

for (let i = 0; ++i < 12; console.log(search(tree, i)));
```

A somewhat more generic design would return the node itself and let the caller access the `.label` property if they want to, or use the object in some other manner.

Note that JSON is purely a string format for serialized (stringified, raw) data. Once you've deserialized JSON into a JavaScript object structure, as is here, it's no longer JSON.

Answer (score 3):

`scan` can be written recursively using a third parameter that models a queue of nodes to scan

```
const scan = (id, tree = {}, queue = [ tree ]) =>
  // if id matches node id, return node label
  id === tree.id
    ? tree.label

  // base case: queue is empty
  // id was not found, return false
  : queue.length === 0
    ? false

  // inductive case: at least one node
  // recur on next tree node, append node children to queue
  : scan (id, queue[0], queue.slice(1).concat(queue[0].child))
```

Becauase JavaScript supports default arguments, the call site for `scan` is unaltered

```
console.log
  ( scan (1, tree)  // "A"
  , scan (3, tree)  // "C"
  , scan (9, tree)  // "I"
  , scan (99, tree) // false
  )
```

Verify it works in your browser below

```js
const scan = (id, tree = {}, queue = [ tree ]) =>
  id === tree.id
    ? tree.label
  : queue.length === 0
    ? false
  : scan (id, queue[0], queue.slice(1).concat(queue[0].child))

const tree =
  { id: 1
  , label: "A"
  , child:
      [ { id: 2
        , label: "B"
        , child:
            [ { id: 5
              , label: "E"
              , child: []
              }
            , { id: 6
              , label: "F"
              , child: []
              }
            , { id: 7
              , label: "G"
              , child: []
              }
            ]
        }
      , { id: 3
        , label: "C"
        , child: []
        }
      , { id: 4
        , label: "D"
        , child:
            [ { id: 8
              , label: "H"
              , child: []
              }
            , { id: 9
              , label: "I"
              , child: []
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }

console.log
  ( scan (1, tree)  // "A"
  , scan (3, tree)  // "C"
  , scan (9, tree)  // "I"
  , scan (99, tree) // false
  )
```

Related [recursive search using higher-order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538352/633183)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const tree = {"id":1,"label":"A","child":[{"id":2,"label":"B","child":[{"id":5,"label":"E","child":[]},{"id":6,"label":"F","child":[]},{"id":7,"label":"G","child":[]}]},{"id":3,"label":"C","child":[]},{"id":4,"label":"D","child":[{"id":8,"label":"H","child":[]},{"id":9,"label":"I","child":[]}]}]};

const search = (obj, id) => objectScan(['**.id'], {
  abort: true,
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, context }) => {
    if (value === id) {
      context.push(parent.label);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj, [])[0];

console.log(search(tree, 1));
// => A
console.log(search(tree, 6));
// => F
console.log(search(tree, 99));
// => undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)