# Looping through (possibly infinitely) repeating object structure

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a problem I can't get my head around. If I am looking for an object with a certain `ID` in a possibly infinite data structure, how can I loop through it until I find the object I need and return that object?

If this is what my data looks like, how can I get the object with `id === 3` ?

```
{
  id: 0,
  categories: [
    {
      id: 1,
      categories: [
        {
          id: 2,
          categories: [ ... ]
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          categories: [ ... ]
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          categories: [ ... ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following:

```
findCategory = (categoryID, notesCategory) => {
  if (notesCategory.id === categoryID) {
    return notesCategory;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < notesCategory.categories.length; i += 1) {
    return findCategory(categoryID, notesCategory.categories[i]);
  }

  return null;
};
```

But that doesn't get ever get to `id === 3`. It checks the object with `id: 2` and then returns `null`. It never gets to the object with `id: 3`.

Here is a JSbin: https://jsbin.com/roloqedeya/1/edit?js,console

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084284/633183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the case. when you go in to the first iteration of 'for' loop, because of the return call, the execution is go out from the function. you can check it by using an `console.log` to print the current object in the begin of your function.

try this

```
function find(obj, id) {
    if(obj.id === id) {
        console.log(obj) // just for testing. you can remove this line
        return obj
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.categories.length; i++) {
            var res = find(obj.categories[i], id);
            if(res) return res;
        }
   }
}
```

hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, this solved my problem. I will need to take a good look at this so I can understand why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the intermediate result and return only of the object is found.

```js
function findCategory(object, id) {
    var temp;
    if (object.id === id) {
        return object;
    }
    object.categories.some(o => temp = findCategory(o, id));    
    return temp;
}

var data = { id: 0, categories: [{ id: 1, categories: [{ id: 2, categories: [] }, { id: 3, categories: [] }, { id: 4, categories: [] }] }] }
    result = findCategory(data, 3);
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `.find` is probably more appropriate than `.some` here

Comment: @user633183, no, because it needs the deeper found object, not the actual object, which would be returned on find.

Comment: Nina, I see how you're using it now. Sneaky side effect fooled me ^_^