# How to loop through a key in javascript and check for a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-builder

I have an input array which looks like this:-

```
const x = [
    {
        "id": "neha-1g5te3",
        "value": "",
    },
    {
        "rules": [
            {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "id": "neha-1xer23",
                        "value": "",
                    },
                    {
                        "rules": [],
                        "combinator": "AND"
                    }
                ],
                "combinator": "AND"
            }
        ],
        "combinator": "AND"
    },
    {
        "rules": [],
        "combinator": "AND"
    }
]
```

This is a value which gets created by `react-query-builder`. I can have nested rules inside one `rules` object.
I want to check for each rules whether it has a value or not.
I want to have a flag where

```
if(rules.length === 0){ flag = false}
```

and also,

```
 if(rules.value === '') { flag = false}
```

I'm unable to loop through every `rules` object present inside `x`

Like in the above case, we have 2 outside `rules`, and total 4 `rules` object. I want to check the above two conditions on all the `rules`

I tried by doing

```
x?.rules?.every((e) => e.value !== '')
```

but this doesn't work for nested `rules`

Note: This isn't similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681730/how-to-find-all-values-of-a-specific-key-in-an-array-of-nested-objects) question as here rules object can have multiple rules object inside it.

If I use the function

```
function getValue(o, findKey) {
  const output = []
  
  for (const k in o) {
    if (k === findKey)
      output.push(o[findKey])
    else if (typeof o[k] === 'object')
      output.push(...getValue(o[k], findKey))
  }
  
  return output;
}
console.log(getValue(x, 'rules'))

O/P: [ [ { rules: [Array], combinator: 'AND' } ], [] ]
```

If you see in above case, it shows us [Array] in output. I want to go inside this Array and check for more `rules` object if there are any

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say rules.length === 0

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For the above case, the output should be false as we have rules.length === 0 in 2 cases

Comment: try with this: `const fn=arr=>arr.every(o=>{
  if(!o.hasOwnProperty('rules')) return true;
  if(Array.isArray(o.rules) && o.rules.length>0) return fn(o.rules);
  return o.rules.length || false;
 })
fn(x)`

Comment: @NehaChaudhary did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with recursion.
I used an external variable though to store the result.

If false, then this means that an empty `rules` was found.

```js
const x = [
    {
        "id": "neha-1g5te3",
        "value": "",
    },
    {
        "rules": [
            {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "id": "neha-1xer23",
                        "value": "",
                    },
                    {
                        "rules": [],
                        "combinator": "AND"
                    }
                ],
                "combinator": "AND"
            }
        ],
        "combinator": "AND"
    },
    {
        "rules": [],
        "combinator": "AND"
    }
]

let result = true;

const checkRules = obj => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key === 'rules' && Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
      result = false;
      break;
    } else {
      if (typeof value === 'object' || Array.isArray(value)) {
         checkRules(value)
      }
    }     
  }
 
}

checkRules(x)
console.log(result);
```