# Iterate though nested object and get obj by value using es6+

Tags: javascript, recursion

For an object of this structure:

```
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  name: '1',
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '2',
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: '3',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: '4',
      children: [
        {
          id: 5,
          name: '5',
          children: [
            {
              id: 6,
              name: '6',
              children: [
                {
                  id: 7,
                  name: '7',
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

How would I get an object by value (id)? So I'm looking for a function where if I call this:

```
findObj(myObj, 6);
```

It would return this:

```
       {
          id: 6,
          name: '6',
          children: [
            {
              id: 7,
              name: '7',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
```

Another example:

```
findObj(myObj, 3);
```

Would return this:

```
    {
      id: 3,
      name: '3',
      children: []
    }
```

I know I need a recursion function. Heres what I have so far:

```
  findObj(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      return obj;
    }

    obj.forEach(x => {
      if (x.id === id) {
        return x;
      } else {
        this.findObj(x.children, id);
      }
    });
  }
```

(This is in an angular class)

Comment: search for parent is missleading, because you seach for the item itself. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: yeah ive edited my answer just now haha @NinaScholz

Comment: Consider what it means in the parent function if you `return` from a callback function. Then consider what `Array#forEach` does.

Comment: I implement a generic `deepFind` solution in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538352/633183). I think you will find it useful :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first sight I see some problems.

If you already have the `ob.id === id` inside the function, you don't need to double check for it later. Also, if `findObj` is a function defined in the scope like any other variable and is not in the "class" definition, you don't need to call it through `this`, the same way the first call to the `findObj` you do it without the `this` keyword.

Also, at first you pass an object to your method, but then you pass an object array (the `obj.children`), and also you check for the id inside a `forEach` method, where you pass a function (the `x => { ...` thingy), so when you return, you return from that function instead of the main function.

I've fixed it for you. I recommend you to understand what is happening and learn from it, as this will not happen if you know what you are doing (debug is your master here).

```
findObj(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
        return obj;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) { // No forEach, so when we return, we actually return from findObj
        var r = findObj(obj.children[i], id); // We see if we have any return and let the "check logic" be defined on one location instead of duplicated.
        if (r) {
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are also good alternatives, as described in the [forEach MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description): `There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- your `return x;` statement only returns from the `forEach` callback, not from the `findObj` function. Don't use `forEach`! A simple `for … of` loop will do
- if your recursive call find the object and returns it, you ignore it and just continue iterating. Check whether you got a result and handle it appropriately.

I guess you're not looking for a full solution, so I leave that as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could check the object or check the children.

```js
function find(object, id) {
    var result;
    if (object.id === id) return object;
    object.children.some(o => result = find(o, id));
    return result;
}

const object = { id: 1, name: '1', children: [{ id: 2, name: '2', children: [{ id: 3, name: '3', children: [] }] }, { id: 4, name: '4', children: [{ id: 5, name: '5', children: [{ id: 6, name: '6', children: [{ id: 7, name: '7', children: [] }] }] }] }] };

console.log(find(object, 5));
console.log(find(object, 6));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```