# Find path to object in object nested array

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an object, of which parameters contain and array of object. I receive 1 object id and I need to find its position in that whole mess. With procedural programming I got it working with:

```
const opportunitiesById =  {
  1: [
    { id: 1, name: 'offer 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'offer 1' }
  ],
  2: [
    { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' },
    { id: 4, name: 'offer 1' }
  ],
  3: [
    { id: 5, name: 'offer 1' },
    { id: 6, name: 'offer 1' }
  ]
};

const findObjectIdByOfferId = (offerId) => {
  let opportunityId;
  let offerPosition;
  const opportunities = Object.keys(opportunitiesById);

  opportunities.forEach(opportunity => {
    const offers = opportunitiesById[opportunity];

    offers.forEach((offer, index) => {
      if (offer.id === offerId) {
        opportunityId = Number(opportunity);
        offerPosition = index;
      }
    })
  });

return { offerPosition, opportunityId };
}

console.log(findObjectIdByOfferId(6)); // returns { offerPosition: 1, opportunityId: 3 }
```

However this is not pretty and I want to do that in a functional way.
I've looked into Ramda, and I can find an offer when I'm looking into a single array of offers, but I can't find a way to look through the entire object => each array to find the path to my offer.

```
R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', offerId))(opportunitiesById[1]);
```

The reason I need to know the path is because I then need tho modify that offer with new data and update it back where it is.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would transform your object into pairs.

So for example transforming this:

```
{ 1: [{id:10}, {id:20}],
  2: [{id:11}, {id:21}] }
```

into that:

```
[ [1, [{id:10}, {id:20}]],
  [2, [{id:11}, {id:21}]] ]
```

Then you can iterate over that array and reduce each array of offers to the index of the offer you're looking for. Say you're looking for offer #21, the above array would become:

```
[ [1, -1],
  [2,  1] ]
```

Then you return the first tuple which second element isn't equal to `-1`:

```
[2, 1]
```

Here's how I'd suggest doing this:

```js
const opportunitiesById =  {
  1: [ { id: 10, name: 'offer 1' },
       { id: 20, name: 'offer 2' } ],
  2: [ { id: 11, name: 'offer 3' },
       { id: 21, name: 'offer 4' } ],
  3: [ { id: 12, name: 'offer 5' },
       { id: 22, name: 'offer 6' } ]
};

const findOfferPath = (id, offers) =>
  pipe(
    toPairs,
    transduce(
      compose(
        map(over(lensIndex(1), findIndex(propEq('id', id)))),
        reject(pathEq([1], -1)),
        take(1)),
      concat,
      []))
    (offers);


console.log(findOfferPath(21, opportunitiesById));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, transduce, compose, map, over, lensIndex, findIndex, propEq, reject, pathEq, take, concat, toPairs} = R;</script>
```

Then you can take that path to modify your offer as you see fit:

```js
const opportunitiesById =  {
  1: [ { id: 10, name: 'offer 1' },
       { id: 20, name: 'offer 2' } ],
  2: [ { id: 11, name: 'offer 3' },
       { id: 21, name: 'offer 4' } ],
  3: [ { id: 12, name: 'offer 5' },
       { id: 22, name: 'offer 6' } ]
};

const updateOffer = (path, update, offers) =>
  over(lensPath(path), assoc('name', update), offers);

console.log(updateOffer(["2", 1], '', opportunitiesById));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {over, lensPath, assoc} = R;</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I literally plugged it in and it worked. Lovely. I will now try to understand how it works

Answer (score 3):

You *could* piece it together using lots of little functions but I want to show you how to encode your intentions in a more straightforward way. This program has an added benefit that it will return immediately. Ie, it will *not* continue to search thru additional key/value pairs after a match is found.

Here's a way you can do it using mutual recursion. First we write `findPath` -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const findPath =
  ( f = identity
  , o = {}
  , path = []
  ) =>
    Object (o) === o
      ? f (o) === true
        ? path
        : findPath1 (f, Object .entries (o), path)
      : undefined
```

If the input is an object, we pass it to the user's search function `f`. If the user's search function returns `true`, a match has been found and we return the `path`. If there is not match, we search each key/value pair of the object using a helper function. Otherwise, if the input is *not* an object, there is no match and nothing left to search, so return `undefined`. We write the helper, `findPath1` -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath1 =
  ( f = identity
  , [ [ k, v ] = [ None, None ], ...more ]
  , path = []
  ) =>
    k === None
      ? undefined
      : findPath (f, v, [ ...path, k ])
        || findPath1 (f, more, path)
```

If the key/value pairs have been exhausted, there is nothing left to search so return `undefined`. Otherwise we have a key `k` and a value `v`; append `k` to the path and recursively search `v` for a match. If there is not a match, recursively search the remaining key/values, `more`, using the same `path`.

Note the simplicity of each function. There's nothing happening except for the absolute minimum number of steps to assemble a `path` to the matched object. You can use it like this -

```js
const opportunitiesById = 
  { 1:
      [ { id: 1, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 2, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 2:
      [ { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 4, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 3:
      [ { id: 5, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 6, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  }

findPath (offer => offer.id === 6, opportunitiesById)
// [ '3', '1' ]
```

The path returned leads us to the object we wanted to find -

```js
opportunitiesById['3']['1']
// { id: 6, name: 'offer 1' }
```

We can specialize `findPath` to make an intuitive `findByOfferId` function -

```js
const findByOfferId = (q = 0, data = {}) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === q, data)

findByOfferId (3, opportunitiesById)
// [ '2', '0' ]

opportunitiesById['2']['0']
// { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' }
```

Like `Array.prototype.find`, it returns `undefined` if a match is never found -

```js
findByOfferId (99, opportunitiesById)
// undefined
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath1 =
  ( f = identity
  , [ [ k, v ] = [ None, None ], ...more ]
  , path = []
  ) =>
    k === None
      ? undefined
      : findPath (f, v, [ ...path, k ])
        || findPath1 (f, more, path)

const findPath =
  ( f = identity
  , o = {}
  , path = []
  ) =>
    Object (o) === o
      ? f (o) === true
        ? path
        : findPath1 (f, Object .entries (o), path)
      : undefined

const findByOfferId = (q = 0, data = {}) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === q, data)

const opportunitiesById = 
  { 1:
      [ { id: 1, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 2, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 2:
      [ { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 4, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 3:
      [ { id: 5, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 6, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  }

console .log (findByOfferId (3, opportunitiesById))
// [ '2', '0' ]

console .log (opportunitiesById['2']['0'])
// { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' }

console .log (findByOfferId (99, opportunitiesById))
// undefined
```

---

In this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538352/633183), I demonstrate a recursive search function that returns the matched object, rather than the path to the match. There's other useful tidbits to go along with it so I'll recommend you to give it a look.

---

Scott's answer inspired me to attempt an implementation using generators. We start with `findPathGen` -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const findPathGen = function*
( f = identity
, o = {}
, path = []
)
{ if (Object (o) === o)
    if (f (o) === true)
      yield path
    else
      yield* findPathGen1 (f, Object .entries (o), path)
}
```

And using mutual recursion like we did last time, we call on helper `findPathGen1` -

```js
const findPathGen1 = function*
( f = identity
, entries = []
, path = []
)
{ for (const [ k, v ] of entries)
    yield* findPathGen (f, v, [ ...path, k ])
}
```

Finally, we can implement `findPath` and the specialization `findByOfferId` -

```js
const first = ([ a ] = []) =>
  a

const findPath = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  first (findPathGen (f, o))

const findByOfferId = (q = 0, data = {}) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === q, data)
```

It works the same -

```js
findPath (offer => offer.id === 3, opportunitiesById)
// [ '2', '0' ]

findPath (offer => offer.id === 99, opportunitiesById)
// undefined

findByOfferId (3, opportunitiesById)
// [ '2', '0' ]

findByOfferId (99, opportunitiesById)
// undefined
```

And as a bonus, we can implement `findAllPaths` easily using `Array.from` -

```js
const findAllPaths = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  Array .from (findPathGen (f, o))

findAllPaths (o => o.id === 3 || o.id === 6, opportunitiesById)
// [ [ '2', '0' ], [ '3', '1' ] ]
```

Verify the results by expanding the snippet below

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const findPathGen = function*
( f = identity
, o = {}
, path = []
)
{ if (Object (o) === o)
    if (f (o) === true)
      yield path
    else
      yield* findPathGen1 (f, Object .entries (o), path)
}

const findPathGen1 = function*
( f = identity
, entries = []
, path = []
)
{ for (const [ k, v ] of entries)
    yield* findPathGen (f, v, [ ...path, k ])
}

const first = ([ a ] = []) =>
  a

const findPath = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  first (findPathGen (f, o))


const findByOfferId = (q = 0, data = {}) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === q, data)

const opportunitiesById = 
  { 1:
      [ { id: 1, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 2, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 2:
      [ { id: 3, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 4, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  , 3:
      [ { id: 5, name: 'offer 1' }
      , { id: 6, name: 'offer 1' }
      ]
  }

console .log (findByOfferId (3, opportunitiesById))
// [ '2', '0' ]

console .log (findByOfferId (99, opportunitiesById))
// undefined

// --------------------------------------------------
const findAllPaths = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  Array .from (findPathGen (f, o))

console .log (findAllPaths (o => o.id === 3 || o.id === 6, opportunitiesById))
// [ [ '2', '0' ], [ '3', '1' ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very enlightening even thou it a few levels above my current understanding of functional programming.

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia if you understand function composition, transducers, and lenses, I think you should have no problem with `findPath` provided here. There's no hidden dependencies and you can work out the evaluation using simple pencil & paper method. If you have any specific questions, please ask :)

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia, a strong suggestion: if you want to learn functional techniques, study this answer carefully.  There is a lot to learn from it.  And then go look at some other answers from user633183. At first try to look beyond the unusual code layout to it's meaning.  But then, analyze the logic behind that layout too; it's an extremely powerful style. I have learned more from her posts than from anyone else on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the kinds words, Scott. @GotTheFeverMedia if there are any areas where additional explanation would help, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I am looking into it

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

We start with this generator function:

```js
function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [...p, k])
}
```

which can be used to find all the paths in an object:

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 1, y: 3}, b: {c: 2, d: {x: 3}, e: {f: {x: 5, g: {x: 3}}}}}

;[...getPaths(obj)]
//~> [[], ["a"], ["a", "x"], ["a", "y"], ["b"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d"], 
//    ["b", "d", "x"], ["b", "e"], ["b", "e", "f"], ["b", "e", "f", "x"], 
//    ["b", "e", "f", "g"], ["b", "e", "f", "g", "x"]]
```

and then, with this little helper function:

```js
const path = (ps, o) => ps.reduce((o, p) => o[p] || {}, o)
```

we can write

```js
const findPath = (predicate, o) =>
  [...getPaths(o)] .find (p => predicate (path (p, o) ) )
```

which we can call like

```js
console.log(
  findPath (a => a.x == 3, obj)
) //~> ["b","d"]
```

We can then use these functions to write a simple version of your function:

```js
const findByOfferId = (id, data) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === id, data)

const opportunitiesById =  {
  1: [ { id: 10, name: 'offer 1' }, { id: 20, name: 'offer 2' } ],
  2: [ { id: 11, name: 'offer 3' }, { id: 21, name: 'offer 4' } ],
  3: [ { id: 12, name: 'offer 5' }, { id: 22, name: 'offer 6' } ]
}

console.log(
  findByOfferId (22, opportunitiesById)
) //~> ["3", "1"]

console.log(
  findByOfferId (42, opportunitiesById)
) //~> undefined
```

---

It is trivial to extend this to get all paths for which the value satisfies the predicate, simply replacing `find` with `filter`:

```js
const findAllPaths = (predicate, o) =>
  [...getPaths(o)] .filter (p => predicate (path(p, o) ) )

console.log(
  findAllPaths (a => a.x == 3, obj)
) //=> [["b","d"],["b","e","f","g"]]
```

---

There is a concern with all this, though.  Even though `findPath` only needs to find the first match, and even though `getPaths` is a generator and hence lazy, we force the full run of it with `[...getPaths(o)]`.  So it might be worth using this uglier, more imperative version:

```js
const findPath = (predicate, o) => {
  let it = getPaths(o)
  let res = it.next()
  while (!res.done) {
    if (predicate (path (res.value, o) ) )
      return res.value
    res = it.next()
  }
}
```

---

This is what it looks like all together:

```js
function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [...p, k])
}

const path = (ps, o) => ps.reduce ((o, p) => o[p] || {}, o)

   
// const findPath = (pred, o) =>
//   [...getPaths(o)] .find (p => pred (path (p, o) ) )


const findPath = (predicate, o) => {
  let it = getPaths(o)
  let res = it.next()
  while (!res.done) {
    if (predicate (path (res.value, o) ) )
      return res.value
    res = it.next()
  }
}

const obj = {a: {x: 1, y: 3}, b: {c: 2, d: {x: 3}, e: {f: {x: 5, g: {x: 3}}}}}

console.log(
  findPath (a => a.x == 3, obj)
) //~> ["b","d"]

const findAllPaths = (pred, o) =>
  [...getPaths(o)] .filter (p => pred (path(p, o) ) )

console.log(
  findAllPaths (a => a.x == 3, obj)
) //~> [["b","d"],["b","e","f","g"]]


const findByOfferId = (id, data) =>
  findPath (o => o.id === id, data)

const opportunitiesById =  {
  1: [ { id: 10, name: 'offer 1' }, { id: 20, name: 'offer 2' } ],
  2: [ { id: 11, name: 'offer 3' }, { id: 21, name: 'offer 4' } ],
  3: [ { id: 12, name: 'offer 5' }, { id: 22, name: 'offer 6' } ]
}

console.log(
  findByOfferId (22, opportunitiesById)
) //~> ["3", "1"]

console.log(
  findByOfferId (42, opportunitiesById)
) //~> undefined
```

---

Another brief note: the order in which the paths are generated is only one possibility.  If you want to change from [pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_(NLR)) to [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)), you can move the `yield p` line in `getPaths` from the first line to the last one.

---

Finally, you asked about doing this with functional techniques, and mentioned Ramda.  As the solution from customcommander shows, you *can* do this with Ramda.  And the (excellent as always) answer from user633183 demonstrates, it's possible to do this with mainly functional techniques.

I still find this a somewhat simpler approach.  Kudos to customcommander for finding a Ramda version, because Ramda is not particularly well-suited for recursive tasks, but still the obvious approach to something that has to visit the nodes of a recursive structure like a JS object is to use a recursive algorithm.  I'm one of the authors of Ramda, and I haven't even *tried* to understand how that solution works.

### Update

user633183 pointed out that this would be simpler, and still lazy:

```js
const findPath = (predicate, o) => {
  for (const p of getPaths(o)) 
    if (predicate (path (p, o)) ) 
      return p
}
```

Comment: The process is easy to follow thanks to your great explanation. Inspired by your work, I added a generator implementation to my answer :D

Comment: There is one weakness with `[...getPaths(o)].find` as all paths are eagerly calculated before `find` can start. A solution compatible with the rest of your program might be to make a `find` function that operates on the generator instead of using Array's `find`

Comment: @user633183: There is a version of `getPaths` included that's meant to get around this, but you're right that an adjusted `find` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Nice updates, Scott. Is there a particular reason you're handling the iterator manually instead of using `for (const p of getPaths(o)) ...`?

Comment: @user633183: No updates since your previous comment, but I will now that you've pointed out that I can use `for-of`.  I hadn't tried, but was under the impression that it was also eager.  I just tested, and you're right that it would make for a cleaner implementation.

Comment: The updated implementation looks super clean. I also learned that destructuring assignment can be used to get values out of a generator lazily so long as you're not using a rest pattern, which causes the iterator to step until its exhausted. I use this technique in `first` in my answer, which gets the first value from an iterable but ignores the rest. This effectively pauses the iterator after the first value comes out. Always a pleasure collaborating with you. Cheers.