# Searching a dynamically generated, multilevel array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a Javascript array of objects like so:

```
myArray = [
    {
        id: 'top-id1',
        title: 'title1',
        subElements: [
            {
                id: 'id2',
                title: 'title2',
                subElements: [
                    {
                        id: 'id3',
                        title: 'title2',
                        subElements: [
                            ...
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 'id4',
                title: 'title4',
             },
             ...
         ]
     },
     {
         id: 'top-id5',
         title: 'title5',
         subElements: [
             ...
         ]
     },
     ...
];
```

This array can technically be infinitely long and infinitely deep (through the subElements), but in practice it will only have 4 max objects at the top level and go 4 levels deep max so performance and runtime isn't a huge concern.

**What I'm trying to find:** Given any id, I need to return the id of the top level object that contains the first id. So if I'm given 'id3', I need to return 'top-id1'. And if I'm given 'top-id5', I also need to return 'top-id5'. For what it matters, this is in the context of a React application. Can someone help me figure out an algorithm to do so?

Comment: A DFS/BFS "tree traversal" type search algorithm would be what you are looking for, depending on which result you wanted to return. You probably want the DFS (depth first search) one.

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate, but the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066101 can probably help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your case.

```js
const myArray = [{ id: 'top-id1', title: 'title1', subElements: [{ id: 'id2', title: 'title2', subElements: [{ id: 'id3', title: 'title2', subElements: [ ] }] }, { id: 'id4', title: 'title4', }, ] }, { id: 'top-id5', title: 'title5', subElements: [ ] }, ];

function searchTree(element, matchingId) {
  if (element.id == matchingId) {
    return element;
  } else if (element.subElements != null) {
    var i;
    var result = null;
    for (i = 0; result == null && i < element.subElements.length; i++) {
      result = searchTree(element.subElements[i], matchingId);
    }
    return result;
  }
  return null;
}

function searchTopNode(element, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (searchTree(data[i], element) != null)
      return data[i].id;
  }
}

console.log(searchTopNode('id3', myArray));
console.log(searchTopNode('top-id5', myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [{ id: 'top-id1', title: 'title1', subElements: [{ id: 'id2', title: 'title2', subElements: [{ id: 'id3', title: 'title2', subElements: [ ] }] }, { id: 'id4', title: 'title4', }, ] }, { id: 'top-id5', title: 'title5', subElements: [ ] }, ];

function deepSearch(obj, result) {

  if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (let i = 0, elem; elem = obj[i]; i++) {
      deepSearch(elem, result);
    }
    return;
  }
  if (!!obj['id']) {
    result.push(obj.id);
  }
  if (!!obj['subElements'] && Array.isArray(obj.subElements)) {
    deepSearch(obj.subElements, result);
  }
}

const results = [];
deepSearch(myArray, results);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Explanation and a snippet is preferred. I made you a snippet. How to get the top-id from id3?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [{ id: 'top-id1', title: 'title1', subElements: [{ id: 'id2', title: 'title2', subElements: [{ id: 'id3', title: 'title2', subElements: [ ] }] }, { id: 'id4', title: 'title4', }, ] }, { id: 'top-id5', title: 'title5', subElements: [ ] }, ];


function findRoot(array, id) {
  let node = null
  array.forEach(x => {
    if (x.id == id) {
      node = x
    } else {
      if (x.subElements) {
        let found = findRoot(x.subElements, id)
        if (found)
          node = x
      }
    }
    if (node)
      return
  })
  return node
}

var result = findRoot(myArray, 'id3')
if (result && result.id)
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result.id
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Maybe something like this?

Comment: If you click `[<>]` you can make a [mcve] to show it works. Here is the array: `const myArray = [{ id: 'top-id1', title: 'title1', subElements: [{ id: 'id2', title: 'title2', subElements: [{ id: 'id3', title: 'title2', subElements: [ ] }] }, { id: 'id4', title: 'title4', }, ] }, { id: 'top-id5', title: 'title5', subElements: [ ] }, ];
`