# Recursive search of objects returning the path in js

Tags: javascript, recursion, search

I am writing a function to search nested js objects for keys or values, returning hits and their paths.
At the moment, the path concatenation of the search stages does not work yet. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Given this test data:

```js
let object = {
    'id' : '1',
    'items' : [
        'knive', 'blue flower', 'scissor'
    ],
    'nested' : {
        'array1' : ['gold', 'silver'],
        'array2' : ['blue', 'knive'],
    }

}

let argument = 'knive';
```

and this code:

```js
let pincushion = [];

find(argument, object, pincushion);

function find(needle, heyheap, pincushion, path = '') {

    for (let pitchfork in heyheap) {

        if (typeof(heyheap[pitchfork]) === 'object') {

            if (path.length == 0) {
                path = pitchfork.toString();
            } else {
                path = path.concat('.').concat(pitchfork);
            }

            find(needle, heyheap[pitchfork], pincushion, path);
            if (path.length > 0) {
                let split = path.split('.');
                path = path.substring(0, path.length - split[split.length - 1].length - 1);
            }

        } else if (pitchfork === needle || heyheap[pitchfork] === needle) {            

            let key = pitchfork.toString();
            let value = heyheap[pitchfork].toString();
            let pin = 'key: '.concat(key).concat(', value: ').concat(value).concat(', path: ').concat(path);
            pincushion.push(pin);
        }
    }
}
```

i get following results:

```js
[ 'key: 0, value: knive, path: items',
  'key: 1, value: knive, path: items.nested.array1.array2' ]
```

but i want to have those:

```js
[ 'key: 0, value: knive, path: items',
  'key: 1, value: knive, path: nested.array2' ]
```

Comment: do you have some data to test? and the (wanted) result?

Comment: i added an example to make it more clear.

Comment: please add the data of the call of the function as well.

Comment: it's the second line of the code snippet. or which call?
i edited the `argument` value to the test snippet.

Comment: You might want to see the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the `path` because strings are immuatable.

```
path = path.concat('.').concat(pitchfork);
```

Comment: Yes, i did that and edited my question. But it's not quite what i wanted yet.