# How to obtain a master structure for a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
[
    {
        "dog": "lmn",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "x": 4
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "a": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dog": "pqr",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "m": 3
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "n": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ],
        "lion": 90
    }
]
```

I want to transform this to obtain all possible properties of any object at any nesting level. For arrays, the first object should contain all the properties. The values are trivial, but the below solution considers the first encountered value for any property. (For ex. "lmn" is preserved for the "dog" property)
Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "dog": "lmn",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "x": 4,
                        "n": 8
                    },
                    "width": {
                        "a": 8,
                        "m": 3
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b",
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ],
        "lion": 90
    }
]
```

Here's a recursive function I tried before this nesting problem struck me

```js
function consolidateArray(json) {
    if (Array.isArray(json)) {
      const reference = json[0];
      json.forEach(function(element) {
        for (var key in element) {
          if (!reference.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            reference[key] = element[key];
          }
        }
      });
      json.splice(1);
      this.consolidateArray(json[0]);
    } else if (typeof json === 'object') {
      for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.consolidateArray(json[key]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
var json = [
    {
        "dog": "lmn",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "x": 4
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "a": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dog": "pqr",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "m": 3
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "n": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ],
        "lion": 90
    }
];
consolidateArray(json);
alert(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
```

Comment: can you add, what you have tried
?

Comment: @Tom Your answer seems to deal with multiple values, with the structure and keys of the respective objects being identical. However, as in my question, the structure may be different for each object in the array and multiple values for the keys do not need to be preserved.

Comment: @Harish I've written a function that recursively expands the object, but it doesn't work when the properties have different grandparents. You can have a look at it (TypeScript) here: http://notepad.pw/code/p4xps5h1

Comment: @Tom Thanks for clarifying. I'll see if I can make it work. Explicit steps are always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting problem.  Here's what I came up with:

```js
// Utility functions

const isInt = Number.isInteger

const path = (ps = [], obj = {}) =>
  ps .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const assoc = (prop, val, obj) => 
  isInt (prop) && Array .isArray (obj)
    ? [... obj .slice (0, prop), val, ...obj .slice (prop + 1)]
    : {...obj, [prop]: val}

const assocPath = ([p = undefined, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  p == undefined
    ? obj
    : ps.length == 0
      ? assoc(p, val, obj)
      : assoc(p, assocPath(ps, val, obj[p] || (obj[p] = isInt(ps[0]) ? [] : {})), obj)


// Helper functions

function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  if (Object(o) !== o || Object .keys (o) .length == 0) yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [...p, isInt (Number (k)) ? Number (k) : k])
}

const canonicalPath = (path) =>
  path.map (n => isInt (Number (n)) ? 0 : n)

const splitPaths = (xs) => 
  Object .values ( xs.reduce ( 
    (a, p, _, __, cp = canonicalPath (p), key = cp .join ('\u0000')) => 
      ({...a, [key]: a [key] || {canonical: cp, path: p} })
    , {}
  ))


// Main function

const canonicalRep = (data) => splitPaths ([...getPaths (data)]) 
  .reduce (
    (a, {path:p, canonical}) => assocPath(canonical, path(p, data), a),
    Array.isArray(data) ? [] : {}
  ) 


  // Test

const data = [{"dog": "lmn", "tiger": [{"bengoltiger": {"height": {"x": 4}}, "indiantiger": {"foor": "b", "paw": "a"}}, {"bengoltiger": {"width": {"a": 8}}, "indiantiger": {"b": 3}}]}, {"dog": "pqr", "lion": 90, "tiger": [{"bengoltiger": {"width": {"m": 3}}, "indiantiger": {"foor": "b", "paw": "a"}}, {"bengoltiger": {"height": {"n": 8}}, "indiantiger": {"b": 3}}]}]

console .log (
  canonicalRep (data)
)
```

The first few functions are plain utility functions that I would keep in a system library.  They have plenty of uses outside this code:

- `isInt` is simply a first-class function alias to `Number.isInteger`
- `path` finds the nested property of an object along a given pathway

  ```
  path(['b', 1, 'c'], {a: 10, b: [{c: 20, d: 30}, {c: 40}], e: 50}) //=> 40
  ```
- `assoc` returns a new object cloning your original, but with the value of a certain property set to or replaced with the supplied one.

  ```
  assoc('c', 42, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}) //=> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 42, d: 4}
  ```

  Note that internal objects are shared by reference where possible.
- `assocPath` does this same thing, but with a deeper path, building nodes as needed.

  ```
  assocPath(['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd'], 42, {a: {b: [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], e: 3})
      //=> {a: {b: [{x: 1}, {c: {d: 42}, x: 2}], e: 3}}
  ```

Except for `isInt`, these borrow their APIs from [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/). (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)  But these are unique implementations.

The next function, `getPaths`, is an adaptation of one from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56086817).  It lists all the paths in your object in the format used by `path` and `assocPath`, returning an array of values which are integers if the relevant nested object is an array and strings otherwise.  Unlike the function from which is was borrowed, it only returns paths to leaf values.

For your original object, it returns an iterator for this data:

```js
[
  [0, "dog"], 
  [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "height", "x"], 
  [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"], 
  [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "paw"], 
  [0, "tiger", 1, "bengoltiger", "width", "a"], 
  [0, "tiger", 1, "indiantiger", "b"], 
  [1, "dog"], 
  [1, "lion"], 
  [1, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "width", "m"], 
  [1, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"], 
  [1, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "paw"], 
  [1, "tiger", 1, "bengoltiger", "height", "n"], 
  [1, "tiger", 1, "indiantiger", "b"]
]
```

If I wanted to spend more time on this, I would replace that version of `getPaths` with a non-generator version, just to keep this code consistent.  It shouldn't be hard, but I'm not interested in spending more time on it.

We can't use those results directly to build your output, since they refer to array elements beyond the first one.  That's where `splitPaths` and its helper `canonicalPath` come in.  We create the canonical paths by replacing all integers with 0, giving us a data structure like this:

```js
[{
  canonical: [0, "dog"],
  path:      [0, "dog"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "height", "x"],
  path:      [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "height", "x"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"], 
  path:      [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "paw"],
  path:      [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "paw"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "width", "a"], 
  path:      [0, "tiger", 1, "bengoltiger", "width", "a"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "b"], 
  path:      [0, "tiger", 1, "indiantiger", "b"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "lion"], 
  path:      [1, "lion"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "width", "m"], 
  path:      [1, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "width", "m"]
}, {
  canonical: [0, "tiger", 0, "bengoltiger", "height", "n"], 
  path:      [1, "tiger", 1, "bengoltiger", "height", "n"]
}]
```

Note that this function also removes duplicate canonical paths.  We originally had both `[0, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"]` and `[1, "tiger", 0, "indiantiger", "foor"]`, but the output only contains the first one.

It does this by storing them in an object under a key created by joining the path together with the non-printable character `\u0000`.  This was the easiest way to accomplish this task, but there is an extremely unlikely failure mode possible <sup>1</sup> so if we really wanted we could do a more sophisticated duplicate checking.  I wouldn't bother.

Finally, the main function, `canonicalRep` builds a representation out of your object by calling `splitPaths` and folding over the result, using `canonical` to say where to put the new data, and applying the `path` function to your `path` property and the original object.

Our final output, as requested, looks like this:

```
[
    {
        dog: "lmn",
        lion: 90,
        tiger: [
            {
                bengoltiger: {
                    height: {
                        n: 8,
                        x: 4
                    },
                    width: {
                        a: 8,
                        m: 3
                    }
                },
                indiantiger: {
                    b: 3,
                    foor: "b",
                    paw: "a"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What's fascinating for me is that I saw this as an interesting programming challenge, although I couldn't really imagine any practical uses for it.  But now that I've coded it, I realize it will solve a problem in my current project that I'd put aside a few weeks ago.  I will probably implement this on Monday!

### Update

Some comments discuss a problem with a subsequent empty value tries to override a prior filled value, causing a loss in data.

This version attempts to alleviate this with the following main function:

```js
const canonicalRep = (data) => splitPaths ([...getPaths (data)]) 
  .reduce (
    (a, {path: p, canonical}, _, __, val = path(p, data)) => 
      isEmpty(val) && !isEmpty(path(canonical, a))
        ? a
        : assocPath(canonical, val, a),
    Array.isArray(data) ? [] : {}
  )
```

using a simple `isEmpty` helper function:

```js
const isEmpty = (x) => 
  x == null || (typeof x == 'object' && Object.keys(x).length == 0)
```

You might want to update or expand this helper in various ways.

My first pass worked fine with the alternate data supplied, but not when I switched the two entries in the outer array.  I fixed that, and also made sure that an empty value *is* kept if it's not overridden with actual data (that's the `z` property in my test object.)

I believe this snippet solves the original problem and the new one:

```js
// Utility functions
const isInt = Number.isInteger

const path = (ps = [], obj = {}) =>
  ps .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const assoc = (prop, val, obj) => 
  isInt (prop) && Array .isArray (obj)
    ? [... obj .slice (0, prop), val, ...obj .slice (prop + 1)]
    : {...obj, [prop]: val}

const assocPath = ([p = undefined, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  p == undefined
    ? obj
    : ps.length == 0
      ? assoc(p, val, obj)
      : assoc(p, assocPath(ps, val, obj[p] || (obj[p] = isInt(ps[0]) ? [] : {})), obj)

const isEmpty = (x) => 
  x == null || (typeof x == 'object' && Object.keys(x).length == 0) 

function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  if (Object(o) !== o || Object .keys (o) .length == 0) yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [...p, isInt (Number (k)) ? Number (k) : k])
}


// Helper functions
const canonicalPath = (path) =>
  path.map (n => isInt (Number (n)) ? 0 : n)

const splitPaths = (xs) => 
  Object .values ( xs.reduce ( 
    (a, p, _, __, cp = canonicalPath (p), key = cp .join ('\u0000')) => 
      ({...a, [key]: a [key] || {canonical: cp, path: p} })
    , {}
  ))

// Main function
const canonicalRep = (data) => splitPaths ([...getPaths (data)]) 
  .reduce (
    (a, {path: p, canonical}, _, __, val = path(p, data)) => 
      isEmpty(val) && !isEmpty(path(canonical, a))
        ? a
        : assocPath(canonical, val, a),
    Array.isArray(data) ? [] : {}
  ) 


// Test data
const data1 = [{"dog": "lmn", "tiger": [{"bengoltiger": {"height": {"x": 4}}, "indiantiger": {"foor": "b", "paw": "a"}}, {"bengoltiger": {"width": {"a": 8}}, "indiantiger": {"b": 3}}]}, {"dog": "pqr", "lion": 90, "tiger": [{"bengoltiger": {"width": {"m": 3}}, "indiantiger": {"foor": "b", "paw": "a"}}, {"bengoltiger": {"height": {"n": 8}}, "indiantiger": {"b": 3}}]}]
const data2 = [{"d": "Foreign Trade: Export/Import: Header Data", "a": "false", "f": [{"g": "TRANSPORT_MODE", "i": "2"}, {"k": "System.String", "h": "6"}], "l": "true"}, {"a": "false", "f": [], "l": "false", "z": []}]
const data3 = [data2[1], data2[0]]

// Demo
console .log (canonicalRep (data1))
console .log (canonicalRep (data2))
console .log (canonicalRep (data3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

#### Why not change `assoc`?

This update grew out of discussion after I rejected an [edit attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27963982) to do the same sort of empty-checking inside `assoc`.  I rejected that as too far removed from the original attempt.  When I learned what it was supposed to do, I knew that what had to be changed was `canonicalRep` or one of its immediate helper functions.

The rationale is simple.  `assoc` is a general-purpose utility function designed to do a shallow clone of an object, changing the named property to the new value.  This should not have complex logic regarding whether the value is empty.  It should remain simple.

By introducing the `isEmpty` helper function, we can do all this with only a minor tweak to `canonicalRep`.

---

<sup>1</sup>That failure mode could happen if you had certain nodes containing that separator, `\u0000`.  For instance, if you had paths `[...nodes, "abc\u0000", "def", ...nodes]` and `[...nodes, "abc", "\u0000def", ...nodes]`, they would both map to `"...abc\u0000\u0000def..."`.  If this is a real concern, we could certainly use other forms of deduplication.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to write a detailed explanation. I get what the functions are doing, although I'll go a couple of rounds on a debugger to fully wrap my head around what's actually happening. That failure mode is not of concern in my use case.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: My pleasure.  As I said, I found this an interesting problem, and in the end a useful one to me.  I am using it in my own system, with only a minor change, storing the *types* of the leaf values in the output rather than the actual value -- a way to extract a simple schema from an object.

Comment: @Tom: Many of us work in environments where they are supported directly, others in ones where a transpiler takes care of it.  And I really prefer writing and reading code that looks like `const foo = (({a, ...rest}) => ({a: a .map (square), ...rest}))` to code that looks like `function bar(obj) {var newObj = {}; var newA = []; for (var i = 0; i < obj.a.length; i++) {newA.push(square(obj.a[i]));}   newObj.a = newA; for (var k in obj) {if (k !== 'a') {newObj[k] = obj[k];}} return newObj;}`, even after it's properly indented!

Comment: Sure, but for example disabled users using their very expensive and often old machines will not like you if your page will crash few times, would not work, talk, etc. Would you believe that even JSON or DOMParser objects do not exist there ;-)

Comment: @Tom: And if the user has JS turned off, it won't work, either, right?  I work in Node, with transpilers for the front end. I work for a company that requires support for many old browsers, but we dropped support for IE6/7 some years ago and dropped JSON shims then.  I've been a big supporter of supporting older environments, but I certainly don't try for NS3 or Lynx.  Do you have different requirements?

Comment: @Tom: Right, I wouldn't try the snippets in IE.  But the runnable snippets are a bonus, simply a nice addition to demonstrating source code; note that they don't try to run anything but HTML/JS/CSS examples.  And "disabled" is much broader than visual impairment.  My company is large enough that it has an entire compliance department for accessibility issues; we take it seriously.  But we certainly not require developers to stick to ES3.  Babel has let us work with modern JS without issue here.  My question to you is, if you don't like my modern JS version, how would you write this?

Comment: Much longer :-) Btw learned interesting lesson - when made code 100% compatible, it was even more reliable. Made an HTML5 page processing ECU error data (text) - tables, sort, filters, charts, etc. and after complaints of colleague checking it in an obscure FF downgraded code a bit and final version worked from FF ~3 as in IE and even in old Android 4 browser. Strange FF was able to handle HTML5 almost from beginning. Just love pages working anytime&anywhere without special effort just because not using everything possible.

Comment: @Tom: But how far back do you go?  `try-catch` wasn't available in the first edition.  (And yes, I've been coding in it long enough to remember!)  I think that was in v3 along with regular expressions, which I use all the time.  Obviously there's a trade-off between expressivity and compatibility with older versions.  I choose to write expressive code, and in fact, as much as possible to write *declarative* code.  I especially do not want to go back to `document.all` vs `document.layers` code, but you need to in order to support really old browsers.  Do you go that far?

Comment: @Tom: Also, why are you deleting comments from the middle of the conversation?

Comment: @Tom: ok, didn't follow all that, but interesting points nonetheless.  Cheers.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: I just rejected an edit for this.  It looked like it was simply choosing a different style for the code.  The style here is very intentional; I prefer working with expressions rather than statements.   If you have another approach, or even just a style, feel free to add another answer, and accept that one if you like it better. (If there was a fix to the logic, I missed it and I apologize.)

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: I looked a little more closely at the rejected edit, and clearly you are trying for some logic changes.  I think you're putting them in the wrong place; they don't belong in that general-purpose utility function, but in the problem logic.  Feel free to get in touch with me directly.  (<my first name> @ <my last name> .com)  Or open a new question regarding this and ping me in the comments.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The changes were added because the function was failing for `[{"d": "Foreign Trade: Export/Import: Header Data","a": "false","f": [{"g": "TRANSPORT_MODE","i": "2"},{"k": "System.String","h": "6"}],"l": "true"},{"a": "false","f": [],"l": "false"}]`. See the empty `f` array in the second object, which causes the result to also have an empty array at `f`, which is incorrect, since the `f` array in the first object has inner structure which should be preserved.

Comment: @ScottSauyet similar problems occurred with empty objects. My changes were an attempt to fix those, and they seem to be working.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: Understood.  However, these changes were put in the wrong place.  They belong in `canonicalRep`, not in the reusable helper `assoc`.  I'll take a look and see if I can find a fix.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: Added an update to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

General logic using this new JNode IIFE with comments - ask someone more clever if you do not understand something as me ;-)

And level starts from 1 as there is no root object @start.

```js
var json;
function DamnDemo() {
    json = DemoJSON();
    var it = new JNode(json), it2 = it;
    var levelKeys = []; /* A bit crazy structure:
    [
      levelN:{
               keyA:[JNode, JNode,...],
               keyB:[JNode, JNode,...],
               ...
             },
      levelM:...
    ]
    */
    do {
        var el = levelKeys[it.level]; // array of level say LevelN or undefined
        el = levelKeys[it.level] = el || {}; // set 2 empty it if does not exist
        el = el[it.key] = el[it.key] || []; // key array in say levelN
        el.push(it); // save current node indexing by level, key -> array
    } while (it = it.DepthFirst()) // traverse all nodes
    for(var l1 in levelKeys) { // let start simply by iterating levels
        l2(levelKeys[l1]);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
}

function l2(arr) { // fun starts here...
    var len = 0, items = []; // size of arr, his items to simple Array
    for(var ln in arr) { // It's a kind of magic here ;-) Hate recursion, but who want to rewrite it ;-)
        if (arr[ln] instanceof JNode) return 1; // End of chain - our JNode for traverse of length 1
        len += l2(arr[ln]);
        items.push(arr[ln]);
    }
    if (len == 2) { // we care only about 2 items to move (getting even 3-5)
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
        if (!isNaN(items[0][0].key) || (items[0][0].key == items[1][0].key)) { // key is number -> ignore || string -> must be same
            console.log("Keys 2B moved:", items[0][0].key, items[1][0].key, "/ level:", items[0][0].level);
            var src = items[1][0]; // 2nd similar JNode
            moveMissing(items[0][0].obj, src.obj); // move to 1st
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            if (src.level == 1) { // top level cleaning
                delete src.obj;
                delete json[src.key]; // remove array element
                if (!json[json.length-1]) json.length--; // fix length - hope it was last one (there are other options, but do not want to overcomplicate logic)
            } else {
                var parent = src.parent;
                var end = 0;
                for(var i in parent.obj) {
                    end++;
                    if (parent.obj[i] == src.obj) { // we found removed in parent's array
                        delete src.obj; // delete this empty object
                        delete parent.obj[i]; // and link on
                        end = 1; // stupid marker
                    }
                }
                if (end == 1 && parent.obj instanceof Array) parent.obj.length--; // fix length - now only when we are on last element
            }
        } else console.log("Keys left:", items[0][0].key, items[1][0].key, "/ level:", items[0][0].level); // keys did not match - do not screw it up, but report it
    }
    return len;
}

function moveMissing(dest, src) {
    for(var i in src) {
        if (src[i] instanceof Object) {
            if (!dest[i]) { // uff object, but not in dest
                dest[i] = src[i];
            } else { // copy object over object - let it bubble down...
                moveMissing(dest[i], src[i]);
            }
            delete src[i];
        } else { // we have value here, check if it does not exist, move and delete source
            if (!dest[i]) {
                dest[i] = src[i];
                delete src[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

// JSON_Node_Iterator_IIFE.js
'use strict';
var JNode = (function (jsNode) {

    function JNode(json, parent, pred, key, obj, fill) {
        var node, pred = null;
        if (parent === undefined) {
            parent = null;
        } else if (fill) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.pred = pred;
            this.node = null;
            this.next = null;
            this.key = key;
            this.obj = obj;
            return this;
        }
        var current;
        var parse = (json instanceof Array);
        for (var child in json) {
            if (parse) child = parseInt(child);
            var sub = json[child];
            node = new JNode(null, parent, pred, child, sub, true);
            if (pred) {
                pred.next = node;
                node.pred = pred;
            }
            if (!current) current = node;
            pred = node;
        }
        return current;
    }

    JNode.prototype = {
        get hasNode() {
            if (this.node) return this.node;
            return (this.obj instanceof Object);
        },
        get hasOwnKey() { return this.key && (typeof this.key != "number"); },
        get level() {
            var level = 1, i = this;
            while(i = i.parent) level++;
            return level;
        },
        Down: function() {
            if (!this.node && this.obj instanceof Object) {
                this.node = new JNode(this.obj, this);
            }
            return this.node;
        },
        Stringify: function() { // Raw test stringify - #s are taken same as strings
            var res;
            if (typeof this.key == "number") {
                res = '[';
                var i = this;
                do {
                    if (i.node) res += i.node.Stringify();
                    else res += "undefined";
                    i = i.next;
                    if (i) res += ','
                } while(i);
                res += ']';
            } else {
                res = '{' + '"' + this.key + '":';
                res += (this.node?this.node.Stringify():this.hasNode?"undefined":'"'+this.obj+'"');
                var i = this;
                while (i = i.next) {
                    res += ',' + '"' + i.key + '":';
                    if (i.node) res += i.node.Stringify();
                    else {
                        if (i.obj instanceof Object) res += "undefined";
                        else res += '"' + i.obj + '"';
                    }
                };
                res += '}';
            }
            return res;
        },
        DepthFirst: function () {
            if (this == null) return 0; // exit sign
            if (this.node != null || this.obj instanceof Object) {
                return this.Down(); // moved down
            } else if (this.next != null) {
                return this.next;// moved right
            } else {
                var i = this;
                while (i != null) {
                    if (i.next != null) {
                        return i.next; // returned up & moved next
                    }
                    i = i.parent;
                }
            }
            return 0; // exit sign
        }
    }

    return JNode;
})();

// Fire test
DamnDemo();
function DemoJSON() {
    return [
    {
        "dog": "lmn",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "x": 4
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "a": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dog": "pqr",
        "tiger": [
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "width": {
                        "m": 3
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "paw": "a",
                    "foor": "b"
                }
            },
            {
                "bengoltiger": {
                    "height": {
                        "n": 8
                    }
                },
                "indiantiger": {
                    "b": 3
                }
            }
        ],
        "lion": 90
    }
]
;}
```

Comment: There may be some problems on line 24 still in case JSON is longer - more than 2 items in array (tiger for example) - there are no back iterators yet and it will copy items left (1->0, 2->1, etc.), then pop last and move from parent to child, so to index 0 each time. But not sure if it is a problem here - let me know if you will need to fix that. But at least acceptance would be nice for current effort...

Comment: Or another option is to copy to a new JSON and do not care about coppied originals remaining at all...

Comment: Damn my man (apologies if you aren't one). I can't even begin to comprehend the mental gymnastics it took to achieve (fairly new here). Kudos for effort. I'll surely be testing for those conditions you mentioned and let you know if anything breaks.

Comment: Do not want me to test it more :-), but as it is using simplified JNode and general logic, it should work better - at least hope so ;-). Maybe I can put some logic used down to JNode IIFE / object

Comment: It's out of my current capabilities to evaluate which solution was better. Apologies if you were offended by my lack of response.