# Ramda recursive merge based on keys' match

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have two lists of nodes, who shaped like so:

```
interface TreeNode {
    data: {
        name: string,
        sharedProp: boolean,
        oldProp: boolean
    },
    children: TreeNode[],
    parents: TreeNode[],
    thereAreSomeShallowProps: any,
}
```

The full dataset would be an array of `TreeNode`

What I'd like is to have a function that I can traverse down this tree, merging changes in a `changes` tree into the base tree. Some of the feature it'd need:

- Match the values of a specified key (in this case support multilevel keys), and merge the matches

  - possibly with `flatten` and `groupBy`
- When the values of the object are arrays, recurse
- Resistant to circular references
- Able to work with very large objects (over 100k nodes, at least)

Some of the functions I've looked at (but am unsure how to string together to build the function I want):

- `applySpec`
- `groupBy`
- `mergeWithKey`
- `mergeDeepWithKey`

[Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-bassi-xs1l2) to check out, with some tests that should explain better what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: This question might be better off broken into smaller parts, I can't tell

Comment: Why do you need to use Ramda for this? Ramda is a library, not a framework.

Comment: Will your changes array be sparse?  Even better, could you supply a small sample input and the expected output?

Comment: @ScottSauyet [I created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-bassi-xs1l2) and it has some tests

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the best approach, it's one we can build easily with tools we have around the house.  (In my case, with ones I wrote in [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58045375).)  I freely used Ramda functions here, as the question was tagged Ramda (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author), but below I show an alternate version that builds the required utility functions from scratch.

This makes the assumption that your changes object will be and/or will include sparse arrays.  If not, how do you plan on matching things up?

Here is my approach:

```js
// Helper or utility functions
function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  if (Object(o) !== o || Object .keys (o) .length == 0) yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [... p, Number.isInteger (Number (k)) ? Number (k) : k])
}

const allPaths = (o) => [... getPaths(o)]

// Main function
const applyChanges = (obj, changes) =>
  reduce ((o, p) => assocPath (p, path (p, changes), o), obj, allPaths (changes))

// Sample data
const base = [
  {a: 1, b: {c: 11, d: [{e: 100}, {e: 111}]}},
  {a: 2, b: {c: 22, d: [{e: 200}, {e: 222}]}},
  {a: 3, b: {c: 33, d: [{e: 300}, {e: 333}]}},
]

const deltas = [
  {a: 8, b: {       d: [        , {e: 888}]}},
  ,
  {      b: {c: 99, d: [{e: 999},         ]}},
]

// Demonstration
console .log (
  applyChanges (base, deltas)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {reduce, assocPath, path} = R                 </script>
```

`allPaths` finds the paths to all leaf nodes in an object, with array indices shown as numbers and other keys as strings.  For instance,

```js
const foo = {a: 42, b: {c: 12, d: [{e: 10}, {e: 20}]}}
allPaths (foo) //=> [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d", 0, "e"], ["b", "d", 1, "e"]]
```

That is just a thin wrapper around the generator function `getPaths`, which does the actual recursive heavy lifting for this.  We could write a plain recursive version of this, but generators often make it simpler to write such traversals.

With a list of paths in the changes object, we can then apply the values to make a new copy of our main object.  This is done in `applyChanges`, our main function.  It finds the paths in the `changes` object, and then uses Ramda's `assocPath` and `reduce` to fold them into our main object.

Here we might have some inefficiencies in speed and memory for two reasons.  For speed, we're chasing down the value at each path when we call `path(p, changes)`, but we'd already done the appropriate traversal in `getPath`.  There would probably be some savings in reporting a different structure with both `path` and `value` out of `getPath` and then using them in `applyChages`.  This does not affect the algorithmic complexity, just the coefficients, and I wouldn't worry about it unless it turned out to have measurable problems.  As to memory, this style of `reduce` with `assocPath` involves creating new objects on every iteration.  Given that there is important structural sharing, this may not be a big deal, but for a large `changes` object, this might conceivably be an issue.  (These would not be major worries for me, but I keep such sorts of things in the back of my head.)

### Without Ramda

Because I tend to think in Ramda, I wrote the above using Ramda tools.  But there are only a few functions involved.  `R.reduce` can trivially be replaced in this case by `Array.prototype.reduce`, and we can write our own versions of `R.assocPath` and `R.path` fairly easily.  Here is another version that uses no library:

```js
// Utility functions

const isInt = Number.isInteger

const path = (ps = [], obj = {}) =>
  ps .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const assoc = (prop, val, obj) => 
  isInt (prop) && Array .isArray (obj)
    ? [... obj .slice (0, prop), val, ...obj .slice (prop + 1)]
    : {...obj, [prop]: val}

const assocPath = ([p = undefined, ...ps], val, obj) => 
  p == undefined
    ? obj
    : ps.length == 0
      ? assoc(p, val, obj)
      : assoc(p, assocPath(ps, val, obj[p] || (obj[p] = isInt(ps[0]) ? [] : {})), obj)


// Helper functions

function * getPaths(o, p = []) {
  if (Object(o) !== o || Object .keys (o) .length == 0) yield p 
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (let k of Object .keys (o))
      yield * getPaths (o[k], [...p, isInt (Number (k)) ? Number (k) : k])
}

const allPaths = (o) => [... getPaths(o)]

// Main function
const applyChanges = (obj, changes) =>
  allPaths(changes).reduce((o, p) => assocPath(p, path(p, changes), o), obj)

// Sample data
const base = [
  {a: 1, b: {c: 11, d: [{e: 100}, {e: 111}]}},
  {a: 2, b: {c: 22, d: [{e: 200}, {e: 222}]}},
  {a: 3, b: {c: 33, d: [{e: 300}, {e: 333}]}},
]

const deltas = [
  {a: 8, b: {       d: [        , {e: 888}]}},
  ,
  {      b: {c: 99, d: [{e: 999},         ]}},
]

// Demonstration
console .log (
  applyChanges (base, deltas)
)
```

### Direct Approach

These two versions both use a fairly indirect approach to the problem.  I happened to have handy these tools that let me build the main function quickly.  But I'm sure there is a more direct recursive approach.  If I find time, I'll look to create one.

Comment: Hm, I should note that the main object has over 100k nodes, and each node refers to both its parents and children. I'm worried that trying to find all the paths might be problematic thanks to circular references, and that traversing this entire object might take too long (it needs to be very responsive to a frequent user action)

Comment: If your change-sets have that many nodes, then this might be a problem.  I don't think it's an issue on the main object.  But the parent/child links might sink this approach, or at least require some customization of `getPaths` -- skipping child nodes.

Comment: The changes _probably_ won't have that many nodes, but the main tree does

Comment: I think there are possible enhancements to this approach that would handle those issues.  But the most efficient ones would be straying from Ramda's non-modification ideals.

Comment: I think I can probably use an argument to define keys it should or shouldn't follow to avoid the circular reference problem