# How to update nested array recursively using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, closures

I have an array which contains:
 **name**,
 **id** (id represents the path in array) and
 **children** (optional). Children has the same structure array has.
Each element may have children, and its children may have their own children etc.
Potentially it can be deeply nested array.
I want to update ids for all nested children depending on new index.
I have a function which accepts an array and a new index. The function calls itself recursively if an element contains children.
For example, I pass an array and an index equal to 1. In this case I expect'2.children[0].children[0]' to be replaced with'1.children[0].children[0]'

For some reason nested children are not updated correctly. When I debug the code I see that newValue is generated correctly but in the end I receive an arry with old ids.

```
  {
    name: 'Cat',
    id: '0',
  },
  {
    name: 'Dog',
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Rabbit',
    id: '2',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Little Rabbit Child',
        id: '2.children[0]',
        children: [
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child One', id: '2.children[0].children[0]',children: [{ name: "Rat", id: "2.children[0].children[0].children[0]"}] },
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child Two', id: '2.children[0].children[1]' },
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child Three', id: '2.children[0].children[2]' },
        ],
      },
      { name: 'Little Rabbit Son', id: '2.children[1]' },
      { name: 'Little Rabbit Daughter', id: '2.children[2]' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Elephant',
    id: '3',
    children: [{ name: 'Little Elephant', id: '3.children[0]' }],
  },
];


const updateChildrenIds = (childrenData = [], index) => {
  const newData = childrenData.map(value => {
    const { id, children = [] } = value;
    if (children.length) updateChildrenIds(children, index);
    const splitIds = id.split('.');
    splitIds[0] = index;
    const newId = splitIds.join('.');

    const newValue = {...value, id: newId}

    return newValue;
  });

  return newData;
};


const data = updateChildrenIds(testData[2].children, 1);
```

expected result would be:

```
[
      {
        name: 'Little Rabbit Child',
        id: '1.children[0]',
        children: [
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child One', id: '1.children[0].children[0]',children: [{ name: "Rat", id: "1.children[0].children[0].children[0]"}] },
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child Two', id: '1.children[0].children[1]' },
          { name: 'Little Rabbit Child Three', id: '1.children[0].children[2]' },
        ],
      },
      { name: 'Little Rabbit Son', id: '1.children[1]' },
      { name: 'Little Rabbit Daughter', id: '1.children[2]' },
    ]
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with that

Comment: do pou want an update or taking the item out of the structure? what happens to the same items with same `id`?

Comment: I want to update ids for all children by replacing the first number before dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that, while you call `updateChildren(children, index)`, you don't do anything with the result.

This code creates a new array, and doesn't modify your old object in place.  (I heartily approve of this!)  But that means, when you call `updateChildren` on the children, you really need to do something with the result.

Here is a tweak to your code that will fix that.

```js
const updateChildrenIds = (childrenData = [], index) => {
  const newData = childrenData.map(value => {
    const { id, children} = value; // no default value for children
    // removed the recursive call from here
    const splitIds = id.split('.');
    splitIds[0] = index;
    const newId = splitIds.join('.');

    const newValue = {...value, id: newId}
    if (children) {  // moved here
      newValue.children = updateChildrenIds(children, index)
    }

    return newValue;
  });

  return newData;
};


const testData = [{name: "Cat", id: "0"}, {name: "Dog", id: "1"}, {name: "Rabbit", id: "2", children: [{name: "Little Rabbit Child", id: "2.children[0]", children: [{name: "Little Rabbit Child One", id: "2.children[0].children[0]", children: [{name: "Rat", id: "2.children[0].children[0].children[0]"}]}, {name: "Little Rabbit Child Two", id: "2.children[0].children[1]"}, {name: "Little Rabbit Child Three", id: "2.children[0].children[2]"}]}, {name: "Little Rabbit Son", id: "2.children[1]"}, {name: "Little Rabbit Daughter", id: "2.children[2]"}]}, {name: "Elephant", id: "3", children: [{name: "Little Elephant", id: "3.children[0]"}]}]

console .log (updateChildrenIds (testData [2] .children, 1))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But if I were to write this, I would do it differently.  So here's another approach that hews more closely to functional programming norms:

```js
const updateIds = (nodes, baseId) => 
  nodes .map (({id, children, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest,
    id: id .replace (/^\d+/, baseId),
    ... (children && {children: updateIds (children, baseId)})
  }))

const testData = [{name: "Cat", id: "0"}, {name: "Dog", id: "1"}, {name: "Rabbit", id: "2", children: [{name: "Little Rabbit Child", id: "2.children[0]", children: [{name: "Little Rabbit Child One", id: "2.children[0].children[0]", children: [{name: "Rat", id: "2.children[0].children[0].children[0]"}]}, {name: "Little Rabbit Child Two", id: "2.children[0].children[1]"}, {name: "Little Rabbit Child Three", id: "2.children[0].children[2]"}]}, {name: "Little Rabbit Son", id: "2.children[1]"}, {name: "Little Rabbit Daughter", id: "2.children[2]"}]}, {name: "Elephant", id: "3", children: [{name: "Little Elephant", id: "3.children[0]"}]}]

console .log (updateIds (testData [2] .children, 1))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

As well as a somewhat simpler overall structure, this code also replaces your `split`/`replace`/`join` instructions with a single `regex.replace`.

Neither approach updates your original data structure.  If you need to do that, you can assign this result back to the appropriate path in your structure, or create a function that does the equivalent while sharing as much structure as possible.  That's not hard.  The function `assocPath` in [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340543), inspired by [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath), would do fine.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the value,

```
return Object.assign({}, newData)
```

or

```
return {...newData}
```