# How to provide structural information on dynamically generated JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I would like to publish an NPM package (written in Typescript) that looks like this:

```js
const networks = { main: 1, test: 2, dev: 3 }

const resource = {
  foo: {
    [networks.main]: "hello",
    [networks.test]: "there",
    [networks.dev]: "friend"
  },
  bar: {
    [networks.main]: "how",
    [networks.test]: "are",
    [networks.dev]: "you"
  },
  baz: {
    [networks.main]: "have a",
    [networks.test]: "good",
    [networks.dev]: "day"
  }
}
```

And I want to make sure the user can set the network once and not have to worry about what network they are on:

```js
const myMainResource = getResourceFor(networks.main)
const myTestResource = getResourceFor(networks.test)
const myDevResource = getResourceFor(networks.dev)

console.log(myMainResource.foo) // "hello"
console.log(myTestResource.foo) // "there"
console.log(myDevResource.foo) // "friend"
```

This way, instead of having to write `resource.foo[networks.main]` they can just write `resource.foo` and get the same thing.

The real object is actually a lot more nested, for example: `alice.contracts.foo`, `bob.protocol.bar`, etc. But the way the data is stored, the network is always at the leaf node of the tree.

I've already written the `getResourceFor` function and it works as expected by recursing through all the resources and replacing the networks (which is why the data is "generated" at run-time).

But I also want to have auto-complete work in the editor (using VS Code). And since the object is created dynamically at run-time, the editor can't really know the shape of the resulting JSON object.

What is the best way to approach this?

If you want to see the real code, it's here: https://github.com/studydefi/money-legos

Comment: "*since the object is created dynamically at run-time*" - the object in your example code is not, `networks` is constant. How does your actual code look like?

Comment: @Bergi I've added a link to the real code. When I say it's created dynamically at run-time, I am talking about how `getResourceFor` recurses over the entire data object and returns a completely new object. See this file: https://github.com/studydefi/money-legos/blob/master/src/legos.ts

Comment: You might find some inspiration in [an answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340543) that involved finding the paths to leaf nodes.

Comment: @adrianmc Ok, but it should still be possible to make `networks` an `enum`, and type all the lookup objects by that using indexed types.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I think the OP is less concerned about how to write the `getResourceFor` algorithm, but rather how to properly type it.

Comment: @Bergi: you're probably right.  I'm reading too fast.  Since this seems mostly about Typescript, about which I intentionally know very little, I'll shut up now!

Comment: @Bergi I have followed your suggestion but have ran into a bunch of errors. Perhaps I am not understanding you correctly? You can see what I did in this PR: https://github.com/studydefi/money-legos/pull/1

The error is also inside the PR.

Comment: @adrianmc That's a weird error, given you are exporting `networks`. Maybe "private" means that you also need to export it from your entry point module, so that users of your library can refer to the enum?

Comment: In any case, I don't think it doesn't matter much whether you use an `enum networks` or something more complicated with `keyof networks` - your data objects should be typed by referring to `networks`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this answer: [Deep Omit with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539387/deep-omit-with-typescript)

It's super messy, but hey at least it works. The result is here:

```
type Primitive =
  | string
  | Function
  | number
  | boolean
  | Symbol
  | undefined
  | null;

type MappingToChangeFrom = {
  address: {
    [x: number]: string;
  };
};

type MappingToChangeTo = {
  address: string;
};

type DeepOmitHelper<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends infer TP //extra level of indirection needed to trigger homomorhic behavior // distribute over unions
    ? TP extends Primitive
      ? TP // leave primitives and functions alone
      : TP extends any[]
      ? DeepOmitArray<TP> // Array special handling
      : TP extends MappingToChangeFrom // IF type equals to { address: { [networkIds: number]: string } }
      ? Omit<TP, "address"> & MappingToChangeTo // Change to { address: string }
      : DeepOmit<TP>
    : never;
};

type DeepOmit<T> = T extends Primitive ? T : DeepOmitHelper<T>;

type DeepOmitArray<T extends any[]> = {
  [P in keyof T]: DeepOmit<T[P]>;
};

type RawLegos = typeof rawLegos;
type RawLegosWithoutNetworkId = DeepOmit<RawLegos>;

const isValidObject = (obj: unknown) => typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null;

// Recursively goes through each field, and changes the address value to the specific value
// i.e. compound.cDai.address[mainnet] = 0x...
//      becomes:
//      compound.cDai.address = 0x....
export const changeAddressValue = (
  networkId: number,
  immutableObj: RawLegos,
): RawLegosWithoutNetworkId => {
  let obj = immutableObj as any;

  // recursive base case, stop here
  if (!isValidObject(immutableObj)) {
    return obj;
  }

  // desctructure the object to create new reference
  obj = { ...immutableObj };
  // iterating over the object using for..in
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) continue; // ignore arrays (e.g. ABIs)
    if (!isValidObject(obj[key])) continue; // ignore non-valid objects

    if (key === "address") {
      obj[key] = obj.address[networkId] || null;
    } else {
      obj[key] = changeAddressValue(networkId, obj[key]);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```