# How can I change a part of json obj in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "left_margin": 2,
        "right_margin": 2,
        "receipt": {
            "emptyLine": "",
            "id": 133,
            "name": "depositOnline",
            "line": [{
                "dataItem": [{
                    "ref": "depositAmount",
                    "label": "receipt.deposit.amountLabel"
                }, {
                    "ref": "currency"
                }]
            }, {
                "dataItem": [{
                    "ref": "depositCustomerName",
                    "label": "transfer.confirm.name"
                }, {
                    "ref": "currency"
                }]
            }],
            "dataItem": [{
                "text": "receipt.deposit.explanationDone"
            }, {
                "ref": "depositNumber",
                "label": "receipt.deposit.numberLabel.deposit"
            }, {
                "ref": "depositResolve"
            }],
            "portion": [{
                "id": 1
            }, {
                "id": 4
            }, {
                "id": 5
            }, {
                "id": 2
            }]
        },
        "portion": [{
            "id": 1,
            "lineFiller": {
                "char": "-"
            },
            "align": "center",
            "name": "header",
            "line": {
                "dataItem": [{
                    "ref": "date"
                }, {
                    "ref": "time"
                }, {
                    "ref": "trace",
                    "label": "traceLabel"
                }]
            },
            "dataItem": [{
                "ref": "bankName",
                "print_type": "bold"
            }, {
                "ref": "terminalName"
            }, {
                "ref": "terminalId"
            }, {
                "ref": "receiptTitle"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "lineFiller": {
                "char": "-"
            },
            "name": "footer",
            "dataItem": {
                "ref": "motto"
            }
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "cardNumber",
            "dataItem": {
                "ref": "cardNumber",
                "label": "cardNumberLabel"
            }
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "rrnNumber",
            "dataItem": {
                "ref": "rrn",
                "label": "rrnLabel"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to find all the portion keys in this JSON and replace their bodies in receipt keys with portion definitions. Is there a function for something like this? I tried some solutions myself, I wrote a recursive method but it did not work. Could anybody give me an idea on how to do it?

Comment: Show us the output you want to get and it's gonna be easier for us to help you

Comment: You can try my JSON iterator https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js to traverse your JSON non-recursive - quite complicated usecase for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008420/how-to-obtain-a-master-structure-for-a-json-file#58013072 It has also 2 predefined iterators DepthFirst and BreadthFirst.

Comment: If the JSON above is `data`, the code  
`data.doc.receipt.portion.map(keys=>data.doc.portion.filter(def=> def.id==keys.id)[0])` should do what you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to map the items in `data.doc.receipt.portion` to their corresponding `data.doc.portion` value by finding the matching `id` field.

You can delete the `portion` key from `data.doc` after you are finished.

```js
let data = getData();
data.doc.receipt.portion = data.doc.receipt.portion.map(p => {
  return data.doc.portion.find(p1 => p.id === p1.id);
});
delete data.doc.portion;

console.log(data)

function getData() {
  return {
    "doc": {
      "left_margin": 2,
      "right_margin": 2,
      "receipt": {
        "emptyLine": "",
        "id": 133,
        "name": "depositOnline",
        "line": [{
          "dataItem": [{
            "ref": "depositAmount",
            "label": "receipt.deposit.amountLabel"
          }, {
            "ref": "currency"
          }]
        }, {
          "dataItem": [{
            "ref": "depositCustomerName",
            "label": "transfer.confirm.name"
          }, {
            "ref": "currency"
          }]
        }],
        "dataItem": [{
          "text": "receipt.deposit.explanationDone"
        }, {
          "ref": "depositNumber",
          "label": "receipt.deposit.numberLabel.deposit"
        }, {
          "ref": "depositResolve"
        }],
        "portion": [{
          "id": 1
        }, {
          "id": 4
        }, {
          "id": 5
        }, {
          "id": 2
        }]
      },
      "portion": [{
        "id": 1,
        "lineFiller": {
          "char": "-"
        },
        "align": "center",
        "name": "header",
        "line": {
          "dataItem": [{
            "ref": "date"
          }, {
            "ref": "time"
          }, {
            "ref": "trace",
            "label": "traceLabel"
          }]
        },
        "dataItem": [{
          "ref": "bankName",
          "print_type": "bold"
        }, {
          "ref": "terminalName"
        }, {
          "ref": "terminalId"
        }, {
          "ref": "receiptTitle"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "lineFiller": {
          "char": "-"
        },
        "name": "footer",
        "dataItem": {
          "ref": "motto"
        }
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "cardNumber",
        "dataItem": {
          "ref": "cardNumber",
          "label": "cardNumberLabel"
        }
      }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "rrnNumber",
        "dataItem": {
          "ref": "rrn",
          "label": "rrnLabel"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```